# How do I handle multiple streams and exceptions in Async PRAW correctly vs. PRAW?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, reddit, praw

I've been using PRAW in my Discord bot to look for new posts in a subreddit using a subreddit stream, and post them to Discord when something new shows up.

Reddit sometimes gives HTTP 503 errors, and this used to break the stream completely. With a little research, I found that I need to re-create the stream object after an exception occurs to compensate. This was my function's structure and it worked well:

```
async def post_reddit_to_discord(self):
    subreddit = self.reddit.subreddit("NameGoesHere")
    submissions = subreddit.stream.submissions(skip_existing=True, pause_after=0)

    while not self.bot.is_closed():
        try:
            submission = next(submissions)
            # If there are no submissions in the stream, wait for a new submission
            if submission is None:
                await asyncio.sleep(30)
            # Code to send the post to Discord goes here
        except Exception as e:
            # Code to send me notification about error goes here
            # Wait for reddit to recover
            await asyncio.sleep(60)
            # Recreate stream
            subreddit = self.reddit.subreddit("NameGoesHere")
            submissions = subreddit.stream.submissions(skip_existing=True, pause_after=0)
```

**I recently moved to [asyncpraw](https://asyncpraw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) because:**

- Being async helps in the context of a Discord bot
- I want to add a comment stream to monitor as well, and do things based on that within the same bot, and asyncpraw was recommended to me

Here's the same function I rewrote for asyncpraw:

```
async def post_reddit_to_discord(self):
    subreddit = await self.reddit.subreddit("NameGoesHere")
    while not self.bot.is_closed():
        try:
            async for submission in subreddit.stream.submissions(skip_existing=True, pause_after=0):
                # If there are no submissions in the stream, wait for a new submission
                if submission:
                    # Code to send the post to Discord goes here
                else:
                    asyncio.sleep(30)
        except Exception as e:
            # Code to send me notification about error goes here
            # Wait for reddit to recover
            await asyncio.sleep(60)
```

Note, I'm not re-creating the stream inside the exception.

**This has also been working fine, BUT:**

1. Did I make the right move going to asyncpraw given that PRAW was already working fine? Would it have handled multiple streams? [According to the author, it can.](https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/7vj6ox/can_i_do_other_things_with_praw_while_reading/dtszfzb/)
2. What's the recommended way of adding a second stream (comments this time)? Same function/different function...
3. I haven't encountered an error that broke my stream since moving to asyncpraw. Will it survive exceptions in the same way my PRAW code did? It should because the stream is inside the while loop, but I don't know how to test it.
4. Is there a way to simulate exceptions such as HTTP 503 errors to test functions instead of waiting for them to happen in a real-world scenario and *then* seeing if your code holds up?

If you read this far, thank you so much for taking the time.